# Apply Morera's theorem to harmonic function on the unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a question I'd love to discuss with you. I have a harmonic function $u(z)$ on the open unit disc $\mathbb{D} = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| < 1\}$ such that $u(0) = 0$. Using the mean value property of harmonic functions I obtain: $$0 = u(0) = \int_{0}^{2\pi} u(re^{i\theta})\frac{d\theta}{2\pi} = \int_{\partial\mathbb{D}}^{}u(z)\frac{dz}{iz}, \ 0<r< 1$$ where, in the third equal sign we reparametrize by $z = re^{i\theta}\implies d\theta = \frac{dz}{iz}$.

My question is, the conditions of [Morera's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera%27s_theorem) are met since u(z) is continuous (in fact harmonic), on the open unit disc and $0 = \int_{\partial\mathbb{D}}^{}u(z)\frac{dz}{iz}$. Does this mean $f(z) = \frac{u(z)}{iz}$ is analytic on $\mathbb{D}$? I mean, it seems odd to me that $f(z)$ has a singularity at $z=0$ and is analytic according to Morera's theorem. Where is my wrong-doing?

Thank you.

Comment: But the integral needs to be zero for _every_ closed curve.

Comment: But the radius $r$ ranges between 0 and 1, so we have infinitely many closed curves for which it is 0? But you mean it also has to be for every other type of closed curve contained in $\mathbb{D}$?

Comment: Yes.  That is what I mean.

Comment: And we can’t motivate my application by “continuous deformation” of these closed curves?

Comment: I don't see any way to.  Besides,  it's easy to find examples where the function $f(z)/(iz)$ isn't holomorphic.

Answer (score 0):

Morerea's Theorem says that if $f$ is continuous on a domain $D$ and of $\int_{\gamma} f(z)dz=0$ **for every** closed path $\gamma$ in $D$ then $f$ is analytic. Surely, this theorem is not applicable here.

Besides, it is not even given that $u$ is defined on the boundary of the disk so your integral does not exist.

Comment: But the radius $r$ ranges between 0 and 1, so we have infinitely many closed curves for which it is 0? But you mean it also has to be for every other type of closed curve contained in $\mathbb{D}$?

Comment: Yes, it is not enough to verify that the integral is $0$ for circles. @iaenstrom